# remove Default selection from klazuka/Kal Calendar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

Does anyone uses this calendar ? is there any way to remove first day selection from it? I want to put an  animation(show/hide) on  Calendar frame when date is changed, but this event also  fires when month is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, just remove self.selectedTile = [frontMonthView firstTileOfMonth]; from slide method on KalGridView file